# How to get UITextField String from ViewController to NSObject

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, nsobject

Hi i am trying to pass the value from my UITextfield that is declared and being used in my ViewController over to an NSObject I have created that needs the value in it to perform an operation. I'm just not sure what I have to do, I have tried this

I have declared the UITextField in my ViewControllers header file and created an IBOutlet for it.

Then I have #imported this into my NSObject and tried to call it like this
NSString *tempTextField = regTextField.text;

and its getting a error 'regTextField not defined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If regTextField is defined in your ViewController subclass, then you probably want to set the text field in your NSObject from your view controller. I would import your NSObject into the view controller and then have an NSString property in your NSObject that you can set from the viewController.

```
myClass.fieldIWantToSet = self.regTextField.text;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh right so I would pass it from viewcontroller instead of garbing it with my NSObject... interesting.. yea the delegate stuff is abit confusing I think I need to read it though.

Comment: @tinhead Right...that way your custom class is reusable and doesn't need to know anything about the controller that's using it. Just like when you use a UILabel object, for example, it doesn't know anything about your view controller, but you can set its text property, for example

Comment: @tinhead I rethought my first answer and delegation probably wouldn't be the best idea for this type of thing. Although it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Definitely a good topic to read up on though. It's not really that hard once you try it a few times.

Comment: Cool man thanks for the help and the suggestions, I have read up on delegate before but when I was very new to ios programing... so its probably about time I actually got myself to understand the concept/rules better now that I am a little bit more advanced in my objective C ability.

Thanks again.

Comment: If you like learning from videos, I would try listening to the iOS course on iTunesU. I did that and it totally improved my understanding of delegation.

Comment: oh cool, will check it out, I'm reading books, net, forums and I have also watched the Standford phone course on youtube... this and that, Theres just so much to take in its slowly getting there but every now and then I need abit of extra help :P

thanks again, will be sure to check out the iOS course on iTunues